# Can I view my Windows Azure logs live without writing them to storage?

Tags: azure, azure-diagnostics

I have:

```
Trace.WriteLine("info", "category");
```

Throughout my Worker Role. When running locally in the Azure Compute Emulator UI I can see this output.

Is there anyway to see this same output live for the same role published to Azure without writing it to storage?

Answer (score 5):

DebugView might help.

1. RDP to your Azure VM
2. Go to [DebugView's site](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647) and click "Run DebugView now from Live.Sysinternals.com"
3. Check 'Capture Global Win32' item from Capture menu in the menu bar.
4. You can find the output of Trace.WriteLine()
   [image]

Comment: This was exactly the quick and easy solution I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably find the file it is using if you remote desktop to the host.  That's a bit of a nuisance so I have a background thread on each set my hosts to send back log messages to my office.  There another process dumps them into a file which I examine using [LogExpert](http://www.log-expert.de/).
I can do that because all my logging goes via [log4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/), rather than using Trace.

Answer (score 0):

As you know the Traces logs are created at Azure VM so if you want to see that you have:

1. RDP to Azure VM and look there
2. Have a process to export back the logs from Azure VM to anywhere you want (Azure Diagnostics does the same for you). You can write your own implementation to send these logs anywhere you wish instead of Azure Storage.

There is another option is to open a http port in your worker role (yes you sure can do it and run a very small 3rd party webserver to export the logs directly to web. Not suggest but still an option)

Answer (score 0):

The out-of-the-box solutions for this are somewhat limited (generally involve either RDP, writing to SQL and/or blob storage, or having a 3rd process poll the image and copy logs to another location). However there is nothing stopping you from writing a custom trace listener that writes log entries through a tcp socket.

We stood it up at our company pretty quickly combining something like the following on the Azure side:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647545.aspx

http://robjdavey.wordpress.com/2011/02/11/asynchronous-tcp-client-example/

Then you just need a simple listener on an accessible box (you can even just use netcat or something) to pick up the entries.

Answer (score 0):

You have all the same options you have if you were trying to get output of a headless machine sitting next to you.  In addition to all the methods that folks have mentioned here, I just wanted to recommend using the Service Bus trace listener.  It should be [found in the samples](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=27421) still.  Just wire that up in your role (if you are a bit more sophisticated, you can turn it off and on through config) and turn on a local listener.  In my experience it works pretty well and you don't have to worry about firewalls or TCP connections.